# How can I make a userscript that gets the href attribute contents of every element in a specified class?

Tags: javascript, url, href, userscripts, getelementsbyclassname

This is the html format of the webpage:

```
<ul id="all_items_container" >
<li class="first item" id="">
    <a class="item title_link" href="#942" title="blah blah" id="" >
        <span class="title" >blah blah</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="item " id="">
    <a class="item title_link" href="#846" title="blah blah blah" id="" >
        <span class="title" >blah blah blah</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="item " id="">
    <a class="item title_link" href="#745" title="blah blah blah blah" id="" >
        <span class="title" >blah blah blah blah</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

I need to be able to get all of the href attributes for the elements in the "item title_link" class and then take away the # sign, and then convert it into a url. For example, the first element in the "item title_link" class has an href value of "#942", I need to be able to convert that string into something like this "http://www.domainname.com/index/942/get".

I need to be able to create a script that can do that for all of the elements that are in that class and then navigate to each of the generated links. Here is the script that I have so far that doesn't work:

```
var itemLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("item title_link");
var itemLinksHRefs = itemLinks.href;
var actualItemHRefs = itemLinksHRefs.replace("#","");
var actualItemLinks = "http://www.domainname.com/index/"+actualItemHRefs+"/get";

window.location.href = actualItemLinks;
```

I know that my script is probably way off of the right way to do this but I am quite new to creating userscripts, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I need a way to make the script wait to start for 6 seconds, then get the hrefs values for all of the elements in the "item title_link" class and convert them into a list of urls, and then either have the script open all of those links in new tabs or be able to export those links to a text file in this format:

```
http://www.domainname.com/index/942/get
http://www.domainname.com/index/846/get
http://www.domainname.com/index/745/get
```

Comment: you can only "navigate" to the first link, after that the page's JS stops running...

Comment: a) you can only pass a single class to that method. Use `document.querySelectorAll('.item.title_link')` if you need both. b) you will need to iterate the collection, or extract the first element before accessing attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to set location to multiple links...
and not `.href`, but `.getAttribute('href');`

```
var a,b,c,d, len;

a = document.getElementsByClassName("item title_link");
len = a.length;

for (var i = 0; i <= len - 1; i++) {
    b = a[i].getAttribute('href');
    c = b.replace("#", "");
    d = "http://www.domainname.com/index/" + c + "/get";
    console.log(d); //just to check them out
}

//window.location.href = d;
//or whatever you wanted to do with that...
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the links that the script would be navigating to have to be able to download files and when I use that script it does navigate to the correct urls, but it doesn't start downloading the file from each url.

Comment: Use a function from the first answer here for each of your links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: Could you give me an example of how I could use the function in the link that you posted. Like I said before, I'm not very familiar with javascript yet.

Comment: Just put the function in your file and add a line downloadURL(d); right below d = ...

Comment: When the webpage loads it takes a few seconds for the "title title_link" class elements to load. Is there any way that I can delay the loop for 6 seconds? I need to be able to delay the whole loop from starting because it takes about 4 seconds for the elements to load.

Comment: I just realized that in order for the script to work, I need the whole script to be delayed by 6 seconds.

Comment: just use `window.onload=function(){SomeJavaScriptCode};` for your script to start after the page will be loaded

Comment: the part of the page that takes some time to load is a flash element, so I'm not sure that that method would work.

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){AllTheJavaScriptCodeFromAbove},6000);`

Answer (score 1):

### document.getElementsByClassName

> Returns an array of all child elements which have any of the given
>   class names. When called on the document object, the complete document
>   is searched, including the root node. You may also call
>   getElementsByClassName() on any element; it will return only elements
>   which are descendants of the specified root element with the given
>   class names.

And,

> window.location.href is a property that will tell
>   you the current URL location of the browser. Setting the property to
>   something different will redirect the page

```
window.location.href = actualItemLinks; // will redirect your page immediately when you assign some url to it
```

Probably what you are looking for is,

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("item title_link"); // Get all elements that have both the 'item' and 'title_link' classes.It will return node list of elements.

var itemLinksHRefs = elements[0].href; // pick first hyperlinks href attr.

var actualItemHRefs = itemLinksHRefs.replace("#","");

var actualItemLinks = "http://www.domainname.com/index/" + actualItemHRefs + "/get";

window.location.href = actualItemLinks;
```